# Converge in probability

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

I'm trying to solve the following Probability problem:

Consider $ X(\omega) : [0,1] \to [0,1] $, where $f(x) = 2x \mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2]}(x) + 0.75 \mathbb{I}_{\{1\}}(x) $ and $X(\omega) = \omega = x$. Consider $X_n = X^n$. Prove that $X_n$ does not converge in probability to $0$.

This is what I've got so far:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \{ \omega \in \Omega : |X_n(\omega) - 0| > \varepsilon \} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \{ \omega \in \Omega : X_n(\omega) > \varepsilon \} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( X^n > \varepsilon \right) = 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( X \leq \varepsilon^{1/n} \right) $.

I divided this in three cases:

1. $\varepsilon  > 1$, then $P(X \leq \varepsilon^{1/n}) = 1 $
2. $\varepsilon  < 1$, then $P(X \leq \varepsilon^{1/n}) = \int_{0}^{\varepsilon^{1/n}} 2x \; dx = \varepsilon^{2/n}$
3. $\varepsilon = 1$ (I think that the problem might be here!) $P(X \leq 1) = 1$ because I'm integrantig all over the support of X.

With this, I conclude:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \{ \omega \in \Omega : |X_n(\omega) - 0| > \varepsilon \} \right) = 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( X \leq \varepsilon^{1/n} \right) = \begin{cases} 1 - 1 = 0 & \text{ if } \varepsilon > 1 \\ 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \varepsilon^{2/n} = 1 - 1 = 0 & \text{ if } \varepsilon < 1  \\ 1 - 1 = 0 & \text{ if } \varepsilon = 1  \end{cases} $

So I looks like it does converge in probability to $0$, but that's exactly the opposity to what I was asked to show. I appreciate your comments.

Thank you!

Comment: What does $f$ have to do with $X$, $X_n$, or $P$?

Comment: To my point, you seem to assume that $f$ is the density of $X$, when it's not even a density (so it cannot be a density for your $X$).  In fact, the probability distribution you seem to be talking about for $X$ doesn't have a density.  In some sense, we could write $$f(x) = 2x\mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2]}(x) + 0.75 \delta_{1}(x),$$ but without your input I don't know if this is appropriate for you (it's a small abuse of notation, but it's a common abuse of notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually in the second case. The limits of your integral from $0$ to $\varepsilon^{1/n}$ ignores the fact that there is an indicator $\mathbb I_{[0, 1/2]}(x)$ multiplied to the integrand $2x$. This will change the nature of the integration for large enough $n$ because $\varepsilon^{1/n}$ eventually surpasses $1/2$:

If $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, then there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all integers $n \geq N$ we have $\varepsilon^{1/n} > 1/2$. Thus for $n \geq N$
$$
P[X_n \leq \varepsilon] = P[X \leq \varepsilon^{1/n}] = \int_{0}^{\varepsilon^{1/n}} 2x \mathbb I_{[0, 1/2]}(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{1/2} 2x \ dx = 0.25
$$ and this shows that $X_n \not\to_p 0$ as $P[|X_n| > \varepsilon] = 1 -0.25 = 0.75$ constantly for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. I'm also asked to prove that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a $Be(0.75)$. I'm having troubles computing the cdf.

Comment: @FedericoCastelloRojo You should ask that as a new question on the exchange and of course include all the attempts so that it qualifies as a good question

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use this page often so I'm not a 100% aware of the rules. Thank you